# How to change index in html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code, each class will be toggled by clicking them.

I would like to understand the `data`,`class-index`, in my code,`class-index` is changed and class will be changed aligned with this.

But when I look at developer tool, `class-index` dosen't seems to be changed.

`<td class="classC" data-class-index="0">Value 1</td>`

`<td class="classB" data-class-index="0">Value 1</td>`

Considering this, I add `undo` button,it works as a reverse of toggle,but it didn't work well.

How can I fix it?

```js
$(function(){
 var classArray = ['classA','classB','classC'];
 var arrLen = classArray.length;
 $("#our_calendar td").click(function() {  
       var classIndex = $(this).data('class-index');
       $(this).removeClass(classArray[classIndex]);
       if(classIndex < (arrLen-1)) {
         classIndex++;
       }  else {
         //reset class index
         classIndex = 0;
       }
       $(this).addClass(classArray[classIndex]);
       $(this).data('class-index',classIndex);
 });
 
   $("#undo").on('click',function() {
       var classIndex = $(this).data('class-index');
       $(this).removeClass(classArray[classIndex]);

         classIndex--;
     
       $(this).addClass(classArray[classIndex]);
       $(this).data('class-index',classIndex);

  })
});
```

```css
.classA {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.classB {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.classC {
    background-color: red;
}

td {
transition-duration:0.4s ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="our_calendar">
 <tr><td class="classA" data-class-index="0">Value 1</td></tr>
</table>
<button id="undo">undo</button>
```

Comment: This is because you're using the `data()` method. This updates jQuery's internal cache of all `data` attributes, it does not update the attributes of the elements in the DOM.

Comment: use `attr('data-class-index')` to get and set the value for that attribute.

Comment: Also note that you're using `this` in the `#undo` click event. That will point at the button, not the `td` which has the class on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to the DOM not being updated, this is expected behaviour as the `data()` method only updates jQuery's internal cache of `data` attributes. It does not update the `data` attributes held in the relevant elements in the DOM.

With regard to your issue, the main problem is because you're using `this` within the `#undo` click handler. That will refer to the clicked button, not the `td` with the class on it. You just need to target the right element.

Also note that the `classIndex` logic can be simplified by using the modulo operator. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  let classArray = ['classA', 'classB', 'classC'];
  let arrLen = classArray.length;
  let $td = $("#our_calendar td");

  $td.click(function() {
    let classIndex = $td.data('class-index');
    $td.removeClass(classArray[classIndex]);

    classIndex = ++classIndex % classArray.length;
    $td.addClass(classArray[classIndex]);
    $td.data('class-index', classIndex);
  });

  $("#undo").on('click', function() {
    let classIndex = $td.data('class-index');
    $td.removeClass(classArray[classIndex]);

    classIndex = (--classIndex + classArray.length) % classArray.length;
    $td.addClass(classArray[classIndex]);
    $td.data('class-index', classIndex);
  });
});
```

```css
.classA { background-color: aqua; }
.classB { background-color: yellow; }
.classC { background-color: red; }
td { transition-duration: 0.4s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="our_calendar">
  <tr>
    <td class="classA" data-class-index="0">Value 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="undo">undo</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for good use modulo operator ! I would like to know how to another version of updating `DOM`element. Are there any method..?

Comment: No problem. If you want to update a data attribute in the DOM use `attr()`, for example: `attr('data-foo', 'bar')`